# Symfony 5.4 with lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle - JWT token not signed resulting in JWTEncodeFailureException

Tags: authentication, jwt, symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony5.4

I refactored a Symfony 3 project to Symfony 5.4.
For some API endpoints to work I need jwt token auth to work which I try with lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle (2.16).
My setup is as follows.

..\config\packages\lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: "%jwt_token_tll%"
```

..\config\packages\security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        provider: app_all_users
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~
        provider: app_all_users
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_all_users
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
        switch_user: true
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 90000
        login_throttling: true
```

..\config\routes.yaml:

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

I created pem/pub keys with

```
openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem
```

When calling

```
http://[local_server]/api/login_check
```

with json content

```
{
    "username": "my_login_name",
    "password": "my_pw"
}
```

I get a 500 error with "JWTEncodeFailureException" and the message:

```
Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration.
```

Typing "php bin/console lexik:jwt:check-config" to console gives

```
The configuration seems correct.
```

Debugging into it shows that in "..\vendor\lexik\jwt-authentication-bundle\Encoder\LcobucciJWTEncoder.php" the exception is thrown because the created token is not signed (!$jws->isSigned()).
I have no idea on how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the `pass_phrase` configuration, this exception can happen if that value is not correct and therefore the pem key is not usable

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%' # required for token creation
```